# Untrusted Application .desktop (solutions given haven't worked)

Tags: 18.04, permissions, root, chmod, chown

So I recently installed [Quartus II Lite 18.1](http://fpgasoftware.intel.com/?edition=lite) on my Ubuntu. After a smooth installation through terminal (I forgot to click launch application while I was  still in root).
Now the desktop icon appears locked and says "Untrusted Application" when clicked.
I have checked all solutions,changing permission, chmod +x and others given all over the forum. Somehow none of them seem to work.
Here are some screenshots.
[image: The App Icon and the Error]
[image: The Properties and Permission Greyed out]
Also the folder in which the software has been installed appears locked with only root access.
Here's the screenshot of that.

[image: The Installation Folder]

I really need the software, or a way to at least uninstall this.(15GB+)
Edit:
Installation Procedure:

1. I extracted the files inside a new folder, saw the setup.sh file.
2. In terminal, typed `chmod +x setup.sh`
3. `sudo ./setup.sh`
4. The software was installed.

Comment: Please [edit] your question and mention in details *how* you installed the application. Looks like you have run some commands with `sudo` which you shouldn't have run.

Comment: Yes, what was your steps with this step? `3. Run the setup.sh file.` It should of been, in the folder you extracted the Tar Ball, `./setup.sh`

Comment: Yes, I have edited and added the installation procedure as well.

Answer (score 0):

From your screenshots it looks like the owner of the file is the ***root*** user. It is also to be noted that you can't trust and launch an application launcher for the current user if it is owned by another user *(root user is the exception in this case, i.e. you can mark application launcher as trusted and launch it from root account even if it is owned by another user)*. So you need to change the ownership of the file. Run:

```bsh
#Replace filename with "Quartus (Quartus Prime 18.1) Lite Edition.desktop"
sudo chown username "filename"
sudo chgrp groupname "filename"
```

Open nautilus and double-click on the file and check if there is now an option to trust and launch the application.

Comment: I used the first command for the installation folder and it worked. But the contents inside are still locked. Could you please specify what will be "grpname" and "filename" ?

Comment: I used my username "sayangdipto" as grpname and "intelFPGA_lite" for the second command, but no help, still showing untrusted application. Although entering each folder and changing the owner might look like an option now.

Comment: @SayangdiptoChakraborty I have specified the filename in the answer. To check your group name, run: `groups username`. Usually the groupname and username is same unless it is modified.

Comment: The icon changed, showing the app icon now. Trust and Launch button appeared. Clicked it nothing happened. Probably because only the desktop icon has been given access while all the files under intelFPGA_lite are still locked.

Comment: @SayangdiptoChakraborty What is the output of `ls -l intelFPGA_lite`? Also, open "Quartus (Quartus Prime 18.1) Lite Edition.desktop" in a text editor or use `cat "Quartus (Quartus Prime 18.1) Lite Edition.desktop"` and paste the value of `Exec` and `TryExec` (if available).

Comment: Result for `ls -l intelFPGA_lite` is:
`total 4      
drwxr-xr-x 10 sayangdipto sayangdipto 4096 Feb 23 17:15 18.1`      
For the second one the output is:       
`[Desktop Entry]
Type=Application
Version=0.9.4
Name=Quartus (Quartus Prime 18.1) Lite Edition
Comment=Quartus (Quartus Prime 18.1)
Icon=/home/sayangdipto/intelFPGA_lite/18.1/quartus/adm/quartusii.png
Exec=/home/sayangdipto/intelFPGA_lite/18.1/quartus/bin/quartus --64bit
Terminal=false
Path=/home/sayangdipto/intelFPGA_lite/18.1`

Comment: @SayangdiptoChakraborty What do you get if you run `. /home/sayangdipto/intelFPGA_lite/18.1/quartus/bin/quartus --64bit` in terminal?

Comment: Terminal closes on its own. Anyways, could you tell me a way to uninstall this?

Comment: @SayangdiptoChakraborty Might be there's a problem with the binary. Since I don't use this software so I can't comment on the actual problem. There must be some document like README with instructions how to uninstall it. Merely deleting the folder might help.

Comment: @SayangdiptoChakraborty By the way I believe your question only addressed the problem of "Trust and launch" not appearing. If you found the answer helpful, you can mark it as [accepted](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5234/) by clicking on ✓. Thanks :)

Answer (score 0):

Ubuntu 18.04 as it already had +x but owned by root I did:
sudo chown user:user .desktop

Then I could "Trust and Launch"

Not a permanent solution but got me going with CCVS9.3